# Setting an admin user via the GUI - command line equivalent?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, administrator

To designate a user as an administrator from the GUI, you can simply open-up that user's properties and select the **Account type** as the "Administrator" option.

[image]

**If the user already exists, what effect does selecting this account type have at the system level?**  (added to *sudo* group, modification to /etc/passwd or /etc/sudoers...etc)

**And how would I accomplish this** (designating a user as an "Administrator") **from the command line?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Ubuntu prior to 12.04 assuming the user already exists

```
sudo  adduser username admin
```

For 12.04 and later

```
sudo  adduser username sudo
```

Replace `username` with the name of the user.

If you check the sudoers file `sudo cat /etc/sudoers` you will see this (from 12.04) or similar

---

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

---

The line `%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` says members of the **sudo** group have **administration** privileges.  The commands at the beginning of this answer add the user to the **sudo** or **admin** group as appropriate for the version of Ubuntu you are using.  There is more information here:

[RootSudo - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo).