# Why do users created from System settings > user accounts not appear in sudoers?

Tags: users, privileges, administrator

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 on different machines.

On one of those I had to create a new user from command line (`adduser`) and then I added it to `/etc/sudoers` to give admin authorizations to that user.

Later, on another machine, I created a new admin user from **System settings → user accounts**, but when I check in the `/etc/sudoers` file, I don't find any entry for the admin user.

Why does it happen? Are users created through graphical interface listed in a different way in different files? If that is the case, what are files with the entries of new admin user created?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting an admin user via the GUI - command line equivalent?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/279306/setting-an-admin-user-via-the-gui-command-line-equivalent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't add a user to the `/etc/sudoers` file to grant him to use `sudo` to become root, but you just add him to the `sudo` and `adm` groups:

```
sudo adduser USERNAME sudo
sudo adduser USERNAME adm
```

This is also what the GUI does when you select "Administrator" as account type.

Comment: Ok thank you. 

Is USERNAME listed in some files?

Comment: I read a lot of examples where they add USERNAME to `/etc/sudoers` to become `root`. But I can do the same thing, just adding him to the `sudo` and `adm` groups. Is it the best way?

Comment: Yes, group members are listed in the file `/etc/group`. You can check the lines of the mentioned two groups using the command `grep 'sudo:\|adm:' /etc/group`.

Comment: Using the group method is in my opinion the best way, as it's also the default way the GUI does it and the way your initial user account is set up. Not sure if the groups have any additional effects over that (probably yes, but I don't know them). Also adding a user to a group is far easier and less dangerous than modifing `/etc/sudoers`.